# Karatzas and Shreve - Problem 3.3.19

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales

I'm struggling here to solve this problem, but with no success.

[image: a]

I was able to prove a $\implies$ b, but the next implication is troubling me. In the book, they give a solution, but I think there is some details missing in this solution and this details are the big problem. Here is their solution.

[image: b]

First, saying that $X_t$ converges in $L^1$ to $X_\infty$ doesn't imply (as fas as I know) that $X_\infty$ is in $L^1$. If we want to show $\{X_t,\mathcal{F}_t: 0\leq t\leq \infty\}$ is a submartingal, we need $X_\infty$ to be in $L^1$.

Second, what is going on when he makes $t\to\infty$ ? Given any $A\in\mathcal{F}_s$, is he saying $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_A X_t\ dP = \int_AX_\infty\ dP$ ? If this is the case, I don't know why this is valid.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: $\|X_\infty\|_1\le\|X_\infty-X_t\|_1+\|X_t\|_1$ and if $X_t$ converges in $L^1$ (to $X_\infty$) then $\sup_t\|X_t\|_1<\infty$.

Second: $\Big|\int_A X_t\,dP-\int_A X_\infty\,dP\Big|\le\int_A|X_t-X_\infty|\,dP\le\|X_t-X_\infty\|_1$.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but why $\sup_t\| X_t \|_1 <\infty$ ?

Comment: If $(X_t)$ is $L^1$ convergent, then $(\|X_t\|_1)_t$ is Cauchy ($|\|X_s\|_1-\|X_t\|_1|\le\|X_s-X_t\|_1$), hence bounded.

Comment: I still don't get the idea. Sure the Cauchy property means we can bound $\| X_t\|_1 - \|X_s\|_1$ and  $\| X_s - X_t\|_1$, by some $\varepsilon > 0$ lets say (and $t,s$ large enough). But are you suggesting $\|X_t\|_1 \leq \varepsilon + \|X_s\|_1$ is a bound for all $\|X_t\|_1$ ? Because I don't see how it works, for $\varepsilon + \|X_s\|_1$ does not necessarily bound all $\|X_t\|_1$.

Comment: Don't forget that $t\mapsto\|X_t\|_1$ is non-decreasing, because $X_t$ is a submartingale.